# Programmatically explore feature definitions

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there any API to explore the definition of a feature (like the reflexion for code)?

My goal is for example to be able to do:

```
var myFeature = GetMyFeature("my feature guid")
var contentTypes = myFeature.Definition.ContentTypes
```

I know I can parse the xml files of the feature, but I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to look at the SPFeature and SPFeatureDefinition types in the server object model.

Comment: I saw, but most of the interesting classes are internal (`internal class SPContentTypeElement` for instance), I can use reflection to extract the value I need, but it's not very maintainable